# Cisco ASA 5506-X - Inside to Outside Traffic

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

I'm unable to get traffic on one of my inside ports to route outside. I believe I have the proper NAT, route, and object configurations. The goal is to have web traffic be accessible on the inside interfaces from the outside. I am able to ping external addresses from the outside interface but I can't do so from any of the inside interfaces. Below is the configuration file for further information.

```
ASA Version 9.7(1)4 
!
hostname *****
enable password ***** pbkdf2
names

!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 23.120.179.137 255.255.255.248 
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/2
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0 
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/3
 shutdown
 no nameif    
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/4
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/5
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/6
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/7
 shutdown
 no nameif    
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/8
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface Management1/1
 management-only
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
ftp mode passive
object network obj_any
 subnet 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
pager lines 24
logging asdm informational
mtu outside 1500
mtu inside 1500
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
no arp permit-nonconnected
arp rate-limit 16384
!
object network obj_any
 nat (any,outside) dynamic interface
!
nat (inside,outside) after-auto source dynamic any interface
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 23.120.179.142 1
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout pat-xlate 0:00:30
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 sctp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
timeout conn-holddown 0:00:15
timeout igp stale-route 0:01:10
user-identity default-domain LOCAL
http server enable
http 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 inside
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
service sw-reset-button
crypto ipsec security-association pmtu-aging infinite
crypto ca trustpool policy
telnet timeout 5
no ssh stricthostkeycheck
ssh timeout 5
ssh key-exchange group dh-group1-sha1
console timeout 0

dhcpd auto_config outside
!
dhcpd address 192.168.1.5-192.168.1.254 inside
!
threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection statistics access-list
no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
!
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
 parameters   
  message-length maximum client auto
  message-length maximum 512
  no tcp-inspection
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect dns preset_dns_map 
  inspect ftp 
  inspect h323 h225 
  inspect h323 ras 
  inspect rsh 
  inspect rtsp 
  inspect esmtp 
  inspect sqlnet 
  inspect skinny  
  inspect sunrpc 
  inspect xdmcp 
  inspect sip  
  inspect netbios 
  inspect tftp 
  inspect ip-options 
!
service-policy global_policy global
prompt hostname context 
no call-home reporting anonymous
Cryptochecksum:******
: end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably just need to add inspection for icmp.

> policy-map global_policy
>   class inspection_default
>    inspect icmp 
>  
>   inspect icmp error

Comment: No dice friend. I still can't see anything other than the 192.168.1.0 subnet.

Comment: Nevermind. That seemed to have done the trick, at least from the clients on the subnet, but when I do a ping from within the ASA from that interface, it doesn't go. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding how ping functions in that context.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like ping inside 8.8.8.8? The ASA doesn't allow that, at least not by default.